# Identifying an index out of bounds in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, runtime-error, indexing

So I have this code that sorts fictional census data from a txt. file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    const int SIZE = 900;
    const int SIZEDISTRICT = 22;
    const int RANGE = 5;
    static void Main()
    {   
        //These arrays will hold the split data from a text file.
        int[] districtDataD = new int[900];
        string[] districtDataG = new string[900];
        string[] districtDataM = new string[900];
        int[] districtDataA = new int[900];

        //countDistrict will hold how many hypothetical people in each hypothetical district and 
        //ages will hold how many hypothetical people between certain hypothetical ages.
        int[] countDistrict = new int[SIZEDISTRICT];
        int[] ages = new int[RANGE] { 0, 18, 30, 45, 65};


        //Modules
        ReadFile(districtDataD, districtDataG, districtDataM,districtDataA);
        CountPopulation(districtDataD, countDistrict);
        AgeRanges(districtDataA, ages);
        DisplayData(districtDataD, districtDataA, ages);
    }//End Main


    //This module splits and inserts the data into the four first arrays
    static void ReadFile(int[] districtDataD, string[] districtDataG, string[] districtDataM, int[] districtDataA)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("census.txt");
        int i = 0;

        while (i < SIZE && i < districtDataD.Length)
        {
            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("census.txt"))
            {
                string[] parts = line.Split(',');

                districtDataD[i] = int.Parse(parts[0]);
                districtDataG[i] = parts[1];
                districtDataM[i] = parts[2];
                districtDataA[i] = int.Parse(parts[3]);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    //This module counts how many hypothetical people are in each fictional district
   static void CountPopulation(int[] districtDataD, int[] countDistrict)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < districtDataD.Length; i++)
        {
            if (districtDataD[i] > 0 && districtDataD[i] < districtDataD.Length)
            {
                countDistrict[districtDataD[i]]
                    ++;
            }
        }
    }


    //This module sorts the ages into 0-18, 19-30, 31-45, 46-65, and 65 and up
     private static void AgeRanges(int[] districtDataA, int[] ages)
     {
         int idx = 0;
         for (idx = 0; idx < districtDataA.Length && ages[idx] > districtDataA[idx]; idx++)
         {

             ages[idx] = districtDataA[idx];
         }
     }


    //This module displays the data
     static void DisplayData(int[] countDistrict, int[] ageDistrict, int[] ages)
    {
        int index = 0;
        for (index = 0; index < countDistrict.Length; index++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" District {0}: {1}", index + 1, countDistrict[index]);
        }

        int x = 0;
        for (x = 0; x < ageDistrict.Length; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ages under {0} : {1}", ages[x], ageDistrict[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the index out of bounds error, but I don't know where and how to find it.

The txt. file currently looks like this but will be extended to include more, about 100 or so.  900 is just used as an upper limit.

21,f, s, 14

41,f, m, 22

12, m, s, 12

11, f, s, 8

29, m, m, 4

6, m, s, 12

9, f, s, 2

30, f, s, 1

Comment: If you don't know how many elements you need to store, then don't use arrays; use collections like a `List` instead.

Comment: You should get a stack trace with the exception which tells what method and what code line number gave the error. Also, try debugging and stopping whenever exceptions are thrown.

Comment: How about using a variable for SIZE that adds with each loop?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't konw the length of your arrays, use  collections instead. This will make you length-independant of your file sizes. Using the arrays, you have to set the length of the array, which, as I understood, can change, depending of file - and this will always create your difficulties with *index out of bound* without proper implementation. Using collections you avoid yourself of having these problems

```
List<int> districtDataD = new List<int>();
```

Then you can just add items to this collection like:

```
districtDataD.Add(1);
```

Comment: @Sabotenderizer What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are getting error at:

```
            string[] parts = line.Split(',');
            districtDataD[i] = int.Parse(parts[0]);
            districtDataG[i] = parts[1];
            districtDataM[i] = parts[2];
            districtDataA[i] = int.Parse(parts[3]);
```

Check `parts.Length` before using it. May be any of your line doesn't contain 3 commas(',').

Another possible source of error is:

```
countDistrict[districtDataD[i]]
```

Comment: None of them have less or more than 3 commas for now.

Comment: I think countDistrict[districtDataD[i]]
                    ++; is incomplete statment. Can you please complete if it is???

Comment: I've tried it before with another program and it seems to work?

Comment: Checked the debugging thing on Visual Studio.  I changed the first while loop to (i < SIZE  && i < 0) and it fixed it.  Thanks.

Comment: you seem to pretty active on this site, how else can I contact you and are you busy because I am still struggling with this.  The whole thing I mean.